# I want to use global jQuery at commonjs module

Tags: javascript, commonjs

I developed application with commonjs modules. like

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

This time, i want to change commonjs jQuery module to global include jQuery.

Solution: Change every require syntax.

```
var $ = require('jquery'); => var $ = window.jQuery;
```

But I think, this is not awesome.

Is there anything awesome way? (ex. Suppose...browserify options????)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out **Webpack** because Browserify is slowly dying out. Webpack works with CommonJS and npm, so all you have to do is point Webpack to your `node_modules` directory in the `webpack.config.js` (under the *resolve.moduleDirectories* key) to get what you want. It will automatically pull jquery from the node_modules directory and wrap it in a commonjs-like fashion for you, as part of the way Webpack functions.

It can work by itself as its own build tool, or you can run it from gulp using `gulp-webpack`. I haven't checked but I am sure there'd be a grunt version as well, if that is what you use.

The initial configuration will take you a little bit of time but it's definitely worth the effort and learning curve.

**Resources:**

- http://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/
- https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-modulesdirectories